# I'm getting this error while building flutter application A problem occurred configuring project ':image_cropper'. >

Tags: flutter, dart, package

I got this code from my company to build the v2 of the app.

But the codes are not working on my computer and giving me very ridiculous errors please help me.

Here is the pubspec.yaml file

```
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  hexcolor:
  fluttertoast:
  google_fonts:
  fl_chart:
  pinput:
  provider:
  table_calendar:
  intl:
  flutter_svg:
  multi_select_flutter:
  firebase_auth:
  firebase_core:
  firebase_database:
  firebase_storage:
  flutter_spinkit:
  image_cropper:
  uuid:
  flutter_image_compress:
  image_picker:
  share: ^2.0.4

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
      - assets/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

And when I type flutter un in the terminal, I get this error in the debug console.

```
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Kamal\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_auth-3.1.0\android\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'firebase_auth'.
> Could not find the firebase_core FlutterFire plugin, have you added it as a dependency in your pubspec?

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 51s
2

Exception: The plugin firebase_auth could not be built due to the issue above.
Exited (sigterm)
```

If I'm not wrong, Maybe be it is due to the dependencies, how to solve this. I also tried downgrading the flutter version but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: I would first recommend you to add appropriate versions to each of the packages in `pubspec.yaml`, having no version it by default fetches the latest version which is not appropriate considering the packages keep updating and may break the app.

Comment: Also can you add your `android/app/build.gradle` file to the question?